# How do I change the tint color (background) of a UIActionSheet in iOS5?

Tags: iphone, ios5, background-color, uiactionsheet, tint

I would like to change the tint color of my UIActionSheet for my iOS apps.  Is there an easy answer or custom class which I can use to achieve this?

I have found help on changing the colors of the Action Sheet buttons which is helpful, but I haven't found anything about changing the background color.

Comment: Might I recommend this particular implementation... https://github.com/Arrived/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets

Comment: Thanks for the link, that looks promising.  I'll give it a try!

Comment: That's now a dead link :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API, but you could subclass UIActionSheet and play around with its `subviews` array till you find the one that draws the background and either edit it directly, or add a subview to cover it up.

While this isn't the greatest approach, it isn't using any hidden APIs to it won't get rejected from the iTunes store. Before iOS 5, this is how most customization was done.

[Here](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/12/how-do-iphone-apps-instagramreederdailybooth-implement-custom-navigationbar-with-variable-width-back-buttons/) is a great example of doing it with Navbars.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  I'm hoping to get something already done -- but I understand this it what I'd have to do if nobody else has done it yet.

Comment: [This project](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tweetbot-like-uialertview-and-uiactionsheet-replacement) from CocoaControls might help you. I've never used it, but it says it can be customized.

Comment: That does look promising, will definitely try it out thanks!  You get the check :)

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help. That CocoaControls site has a lot of other great custom examples, if you ever have any other needs.

Answer (score 2):

I am not able to respond to the above comments. However the link provided by @Luke is broken, but I have found it to be active here: https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets

Comment: Thanks for updating the link, looks like a very useful library!

Answer (score 0):

There is no legal API for this, and if you use illegal API your app will be rejected from the app store. The simplest solution is to roll your own interface and not use UIActionSheet.